# jQuery - call function based on page id

Tags: jquery

how can I check the `id` on every page's `<body>` tag and perform a set of unique jQuery functions based on the page's `id`?

for example, I have a page with `id=red` and another page with `id=blue`. On page load, I need to check the id and then assign the appropriate color to a div on the page.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var id = $('body').attr('id');
});
```

The above code will get your the id of the body tag and then you can simply select the div and change it's background colour with $('#IDofDIV').css('background',id), assuming your id value is always an acceptable css colour.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

by using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/),

```
$(function(){
   if ($('body').is('#red')) {
        $('.someElement').addClass('red')
   }
})
```

by using the length property,

```
$(function(){
   if ($('body#red').length) {
        $('.someElement').addClass('red')
   }
});
```

by using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/),

```
$(function(){
   if ($('body').attr('id') == 'red') {
        $('.someElement').addClass('red')
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bodyId = $('body').attr('id');

switch(bodyId)
{
case 'red':
  ...
  break;
case 'blue':
  ...
  break;
default:
  ...
}
```